# no matching package named `sc-network-statement` found

Tags: substrate-node-template, runtime, substrate-node

`sc-network-statement = { version = "0.10.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }`

I am using this package from substrate repo [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/network/statement/Cargo.toml). But it gives error `no package found`. Other package works fine but what I am getting this issue with this specific package?

This is my code [repo](https://github.com/ganesh1233456/substrate-node)

Comment: What are you getting trying to with it? Importing only sc-network is not enough?:  sc-network = { version = "0.10.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }